# IntelliJ red wavy underlines when starting a new method

Tags: intellij-idea, underline

When I start a new method all the previous code gets red wavy underlines. This happens every time I want to create a second(or third etc) method after the first one. It does go away after I declare the name of the new method.

IntelliJ flags it for "Class member declared outside of a class".

I believe it started with the latest update of IntelliJ but cant seem to find a way to get rid of it. Its just very annoying.

[image: Here you see a main method and me just typing the access modifier for a second method, at which point the red wavy underlines pop up]

Answer (score 1):

The issue covering the described case, please follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274893